# I am trying to monitor a website but I'm facing some trouble

Tags: python, python-requests

This is my code:

```
import requests,time
websiteURL = input("Enter The Website's URL: ")
response = requests.get(websiteURL)
while True:
    if 100<= response.status_code <= 199: 
     print('Informational response!')
     time.sleep(3)
    elif 200<= response.status_code <= 299:
     print('Successful response!')
     time.sleep(3)
    elif 300<= response.status_code <= 399:
     print('Redirection response!')
     time.sleep(3)
    elif 400<= response.status_code <= 499:
     print('Client error response!')
     time.sleep(3)
    elif 500<= response.status_code <= 599:
     print('Server error response!')
     time.sleep(3)
```

if the website has a response status code 200-299 print Successful response! and if the site goes down print Client error response! but the response status code doesn't update so it just keeps printing Successful response! even when the site goes down and I only want it to print 1 time and when the site status code is updated it updates too

Comment: move `response = requests.get(websiteURL)` inside the `while` loop. Your `response` never gets updated because it isn't inside the loop.

Comment: also, move the sleep statement to the bottom of your while loop, so you only execute the sleep once per loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would rewrite your code:

```
import requests,time
websiteURL = input("Enter The Website's URL: ")

while True:
    response = requests.get(websiteURL)
    status = response.status_code
    if status  < 400:
        if status < 200:
            print('Informational response!')
        elif status < 300:
            print('Successful response!')
        else:
            print('Redirection Response')
    else:
        if status < 500:
            print('Client error response!')
        else:
            print('Server error response!')
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Why?  Just to separate "success" codes from "error" codes?   And the code you have won't work; you need `response.status_code`.

Comment: Your correct, I will update my answer